# Nessus continues to warn me about vulnerable packages that have been removed

Tags: 20.04, purge, nessus

I'm trying to lock down an Ubuntu 20.04 image by removing vulnerable packages we don't use. I've run a Nessus Advanced Network Scan with the SSH login credentials and it found a number of issues, for instance "Ubuntu 18.04 LTS / 20.04 LTS / 22.04 LTS : Vim vulnerabilities (USN-6026-1)" (https://ubuntu.com/security/notices/USN-6026-1). So I removed `vim` using:

```
sudo apt-get purge vim
```

rebooted the device and reran the scan. But I'm still getting the same issue. The security notice https://ubuntu.com/security/notices/USN-6026-1 only mentions `vim`, it doesn't give the name of any other packages that need to be removed. How can I resolve this?

`vim` isn't the only package I'm having this problem with, I also see it for others (ceph, cups-filters, libreoffice, etc).

Comment: This is probably a question for nessus devs. Most so called security scanners have false positives, which is obviously the case here. File a bug report, or contact someone at nessus.whatever, or just let it be.

Comment: I can't create a login to their website.

Comment: Why the heck would vim be a security hazard?! All you are doing here is making it more difficult for you to edit files. You should differentiate between 2 situations: outside threat:  server software like apache, mysql: do not install those if you do not use them. OR disable the service and only use it when you need it. The other is internal  and if you do not trust family/co-workers you will need to stand behind their back when they use the system:a reboot into a live session gives root access so pretty worthless to worry about security.  Use a decent password for your admin for a 1st barrier

Comment: regarding https://ubuntu.com/security/notices/USN-6026-1  see all the cve's and you will notice all have been fixed so as long as you have updated all security updates your vim is updated. That "scan" is showing false positives.

Comment: Note also you may want to read the USN and indicate that those're fixed. Nessus does *NOT* check the actual installed package version against known patches, you need Nessus Pro with credentialed login for that to function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't figure out how to do this in the UI, but if I export the report as a PDF then under the issue:

> Ubuntu 18.04 LTS / 20.04 LTS / 22.04 LTS : Vim vulnerabilities (USN-6026-1)

there's a subsection "Assets" with:

> - Installed package : xxd_2:8.1.2269-1ubuntu5.11
> - Fixed package: xxd_2:8.1.2269-1ubuntu5.14

Removing xxd removes the `vim` issues from the next scan.